# Why is it "strongly recommended" not to use the env() helper when caching config files?

Tags: laravel, config

Laravel [upgrade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) from 5.2 to 5.3 specifies the following:

> **Caching And Env**
>
> If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must
>   make sure that you are only calling the `env` function from within your
>   configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.
>
> If you are calling `env` from within your application, **it is strongly
>   recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration
>   files and call `env` from that location instead**, allowing you to convert
>   your `env` calls to config calls.

The question the documentation doesn't answer is: **why?**

Shouldn't the `env()` helper, when used *within the application*, still work properly? Can't I still use `env()` after the config is cached, instead of being forced to finding it in my whole project and replacing it with the `config()` helper, as (indirectly) suggested by the docs?

For example, if I have this in my **app.php**:

```
'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production')
```

and it will get cached with `config:cache`, but I still use the `env()` helper somewhere in the code, then is there any reason at all that `env('APP_ENV')` would give me something else than the `config('app.env')`?

And how about the `App::environment()` call - is using it also not recommended after `config:cache` is used on production?

Answer (score 4):

This is because how caching works in Laravel, you have an `storage/cache` folder where is stored a "compiled" version of your configuration files when you use the command `php artisan config:cache`, so it is lighter and faster. In that caching process, Laravel reads the `.env` file and replaces all values using the `env()` helper function.

Now, to access the compiled version of the config, which is normally already in memory, you need to use the `config()` helper, otherwise you would be accessing a file, a much slower approach.

The reason behind disabling the `env()` function once you cached your configurations is to ensure the performance in the production enviroment, because it is assumed it is the situation where the compiling would take place.

In conclusion, it's the creator's decision, you may like it or not, IMO it makes things a bit cleaner and forces you to have a more optimized and organized application.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, I understand the caching concept, it's definitely good to use, but the real question is: why do the docs prevent using the `env()` helper directly after the config gets cached? What's the reason behind it, if any? Even if config gets cached, the `env()` helper should still be accessing the **.env** file directly. If that's the case, what's the problem with using `env()`? And if there's really none, why is it suggested to basically find all those `env()` occurrences and swap them for `config()`?

Comment: @lesssugar That's because `config:cache`is meant for production. Is a way to guarantee a good performance in that enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

Because, all the config files were cached in `bootstrap/cache/`. Use `config()`, not `env()`. In the config files like `config/app.php` you have to use `env()`.

**Example:**

```
env('app.name') -> config('app.name')
```

Comment: No offense, just because Laravel cached something, it doesn't answer the question of why it's strongly encouraged...

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith if your car manufacturer recommends the use of some type of oil, and you want to use other, use it as u want, later comes the consequences or not. just think about that.